# Difference in List definition in fsharp

Tags: list, syntax, f#, initialization

This works ok

```
let staticParams = [ProvidedStaticParameter("filename", typeof<string>)
                    ProvidedStaticParameter("forcestring", typeof<bool>, false)]
```

but this does not

```
let filename3 = ProvidedStaticParameter("filename", typeof<string>)
let forcestring = ProvidedStaticParameter("forcestring", typeof<bool>, false)

let staticParams = [filename3 
                   forcestring]
```

What is the difference ?
Then if I type this, it is correctly recognized aggain

```
let filename3 = ProvidedStaticParameter("filename", typeof<string>)
let forcestring = ProvidedStaticParameter("forcestring", typeof<bool>, false)

let staticParams = [filename3 ;
                   forcestring]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `;` is an archaic syntax (coming from ML). There is no reason to use it, unless you are typing several elements in the same line (e.g. `[ 1; 2 ]`). Also in records, you don't have to put `;` between the fields.

The second code doesn't compile because all the elements must have the same indentation level:

```
let staticParams = [filename3 
                    forcestring]
```

Answer (score 2):

In F#, indentation is significant. For example:

```
let staticParams = [filename3
                    forcestring]
```

two values have the same indentation level, they are parsed as list elements.

However in the following case:

```
let staticParams = [filename3 
                   forcestring]
//                 ^
//                 Notice different indentation here.
```

two values are parsed as function application of `filename3` to `forcestring` and hence an error message.

Since `;` is list delimiter, in your last example F# parser expects another list element in the next line. Therefore, there is no problem with wrong indentation there.